# Language based processing in R: Selecting features in dfm with certain pointwise mutual information (PMI) value

Tags: r, machine-learning, statistics, nlp, quanteda

I would like to keep such 2-3 word phrases (i.e.features) within my dfm that have a PMI value greater than 3x the number of words in the phrase*.

PMI is hereby defined as: pmi(phrase) = log(p(phrase)/Product(p(word))

with 
p(phrase): the probability of the phrase based on its relative frequency 
Product(p(word): the product of the probabilities of each word in the phrase.

Thus far I used the following code, however the PMI values do not seem to be correct, but I am not able to find the issue:

```
#creating dummy data
id <- c(1:5)
text <- c("positiveemoticon my name is positiveemoticon positiveemoticon i love you", "hello dont", "i love you", "i love you", "happy birthday")
ids_text_clean_test <- data.frame(id, text)
ids_text_clean_test$id <- as.character(ids_text_clean_test$id)
ids_text_clean_test$text <- as.character(ids_text_clean_test$text)

test_corpus <- corpus(ids_text_clean_test[["text"]], docnames = ids_text_clean_test[["id"]])

tokens_all_test <- tokens(test_corpus, remove_punct = TRUE)

## Create a document-feature matrix(dfm)
doc_phrases_matrix_test <- dfm(tokens_all_test, ngrams = 2:3) #extracting two- and three word phrases
doc_phrases_matrix_test

# calculating the pointwise mututal information for each phrase to identify phrases that occur at rates much higher than chance
tcmrs = Matrix::rowSums(doc_phrases_matrix_test) #number of words per user
tcmcs = Matrix::colSums(doc_phrases_matrix_test) #counts of each phrase
N = sum(tcmrs) #number of total words used 
colp = tcmcs/N #proportion of the phrases by total phrases
rowp = tcmrs/N #proportion of each users' words used by total words used
pp = doc_phrases_matrix_test@p + 1
ip = doc_phrases_matrix_test@i + 1
tmpx = rep(0,length(doc_phrases_matrix_test@x)) # new values go here, just a numeric vector
# iterate through sparse matrix:
for (i in 1:(length(doc_phrases_matrix_test@p) - 1) ) {
  ind = pp[i]:(pp[i + 1] - 1)
  not0 = ip[ind]
  icol = doc_phrases_matrix_test@x[ind]
  tmp = log( (icol/N) / (rowp[not0] * colp[i] )) # PMI
  tmpx[ind] = tmp
}

doc_phrases_matrix_test@x = tmpx
doc_phrases_matrix_test
```

I believe the PMI should not vary within one phrase by user but I thought it would be easier to apply the PMI to the dfm directly so it is easier to subset it based on the features PMI.

An alternative approach I tried is to apply the PMI to the features directly:

```
test_pmi <- textstat_keyness(doc_phrases_matrix_test,  measure =  "pmi",
                             sort = TRUE)
test_pmi
```

However, firstly, here I am getting a warning Warning that NaNs were produced and secondly, I don't understand the PMI values (e.g. why are there negative values)?

Does anyone have a better idea how to exctract features based on their PMI values as defined above?

Any hint is highly appreciated :)

*following Park et al.(2015)

Comment: What exactly is your *programming* question?

Comment: The question is: What code do I use (how can I adapt my code provided) to find the correct PMI values of each feature so that I can subset my dfm accordingly. (I will try to adapt my question above to make it more clear, thanks)

Comment: Also add the pmi output you expect based on your data.

Comment: pmi is a measure of association, and what's unclear about the question is what you want to associate the occurrences of phases with. `textstat_keyness()` computes one partition of the dfm with a reference partition, to find which phrases occur in the target greater than chance _relative to the reference_. Here, it's unclear what you wish as a comparison set. There are also operators for sparse Matrix objects that make your iterating through the elements approach unnecessary.

Comment: I have no idea how to reopen this, but this is how I would do this using the udpipe R package `library(udpipe)
data(brussels_reviews_anno)
x <- subset(brussels_reviews_anno, language %in% "fr")
## find keywords with PMI > 3
keyw <- keywords_collocation(x, term = "lemma", group = c("doc_id", "sentence_id"), ngram_max = 3, n_min = 10)
keyw <- subset(keyw, pmi > 3)
## recodes to keywords
x$term <- txt_recode_ngram(x$lemma, compound = keyw$keyword, ngram = keyw$ngram)
## create DTM
dtm <- document_term_frequencies(x = x$term, document = x$doc_id)
dtm <- document_term_matrix(dtm)`

Comment: @jwiffels the question was reopened. You should post your code as an answer

Comment: @jwijffels thanks for your input. On the dummy data you provided this works well as the input data is a dataframe with a character vector with one column which indicates the term (which is necessary for the argument keywords_collocation). However, in my example my dataframe has one row per id with a text corpus. When I tokenize the text, I am not able to convert it to a dataframe because the class tokens cannot be coerced. Do you  know of any workaround? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following R code which uses the udpipe R package to get what you are asking. Example on a tokenised data.frame which is part of udpipe

```
library(udpipe) 
data(brussels_reviews_anno, package = "udpipe") 
x <- subset(brussels_reviews_anno, language %in% "fr") 

## find keywords with PMI > 3 
keyw <- keywords_collocation(x, term = "lemma", 
                             group = c("doc_id", "sentence_id"), ngram_max = 3, n_min = 10) 
keyw <- subset(keyw, pmi > 3) 

## recodes to keywords 
x$term <- txt_recode_ngram(x$lemma, compound = keyw$keyword, ngram = keyw$ngram) 
## create DTM 
dtm <- document_term_frequencies(x = x$term, document = x$doc_id) 
dtm <- document_term_matrix(dtm)
```

If you want to get a dataset in a similar structure as x. Just use udpipe(text, "english") or any language of your choice. If you want to use quanteda for tokenisation, you can still get it into a nicer enriched data.frame - example of this is given [here](http://www.bnosac.be/index.php/blog/81-udpipe-version-0-7-for-natural-language-processing-nlp-alongside-tidytext-quanteda-tm) and [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/udpipe/vignettes/udpipe-annotation.html). Look to the help of the udpipe R package it has many vignettes (?udpipe).

Note that PMI is usefull, it is many more usefull to use the dependency parsing output of the udpipe R package. If you look at dep_rel field you will find there categories which identify multi-word expressions (e.g. dep_rel fixed/flat/compound are multi-word expressions as defined at http://universaldependencies.org/u/dep/index.html) you could also use these to put them in your document/term/matrix

Comment: Thanks a lot, very helpful! :) Though something seems odd with the recoding to keywords (txt_recode_ngram): using your example, shouldn't x$lemma be replaced with the keywords? For me the lemma column remains the same

Comment: If the sequence of words is part of the keywords, the lemma gets updated. If not it keeps the current lemma. If you only want to include these multi-token keywords in the data use a simple ifelse logic (ifelse(x$term %in% keyw$keyword, x$term, NA)